# How to get different transition-delay times to addClass and removeClass animations?

Tags: jquery

Using addClass and removeClass I have the following:

```
$("#sidebar-bottom-feature").addClass("display-none");
```

This fades the element as expected.

Then when it comes to replacing the element back

```
$("#sidebar-bottom-feature").removeClass("display-none");

#sidebar-bottom-feature {
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 250px;
    transform: 1s all;
    height: 80px;
    margin-bottom: -80px;
    background-color:#F1F1F1
}
.display-none {
    opacity: 0  
}
```

I want the fadeOut to happen after `1s all`, but then the fadeIn (removeClass) to happen after a 3s delay. If you add: `3s all` to the `display-none` it will add a 3s delay to both `addClass` and `removeClass`.

How can I have different times?

I did try adding another class rather than removing, then removing the old class once it had transitioned but had no change with the transition delay time.

Any guidance would be greatly received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

```
 // wait 1 second before hiding the element
setTimeout(function(){
   $("#sidebar-bottom-feature").addClass("display-none");
}, 1000);

// wait 3 seconds before showing the element
setTimeout(function(){
   $("#sidebar-bottom-feature").removeClass("display-none");
}, 3000);
```

You can also make use of [`.delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/).

If you use show and hide, you don't even need to add a class:

```
$("#sidebar-bottom-feature").delay(1000).hide(0);
$("#sidebar-bottom-feature").delay(3000).show(0);
```